# How to split time series data with breaks in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a overall start date and end date with break dates, and I am hoping to create multiple entries of times series data showing actual dates worked, which means I'll use the start and finish dates at the beginning and end of the series grouped by ID, and use the break dates in the middle... is there a simpler way of doing this other than using a loop?

Data I have:

```
ID     Start       Finish      Break_start     Break_Finish     Break_Number
a      01-01-20    03-05-20    29-04-20        01-05-20         1
b      20-09-19    01-04-22    12-11-19        05-12-19         1
b      20-09-19    01-04-22    05-08-20        25-08-20         2
```

Data wanted

```
ID    Start_new       Finish_new
a     01-01-20        28-04-20
a     01-05-20        03-05-20
b     20-09-19        11-11-19
b     05-12-19        04-08-20
b     25-08-20        01-04-22
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you could summarise the data by `ID` to get the starting and finish dates of each duration.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(2:5, as.Date, "%d-%m-%y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Start_new = c(first(Start), Break_Finish),
            Finish_new = c(Break_start - 1, first(Finish))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   ID    Start_new  Finish_new
#   <chr> <date>     <date>    
# 1 a     2020-01-01 2020-04-28
# 2 a     2020-05-01 2020-05-03
# 3 b     2019-09-20 2019-11-11
# 4 b     2019-12-05 2020-08-04
# 5 b     2020-08-25 2022-04-01
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked really well! What is the purpose of having 'ungroup()' at the end?

Comment: @Hong `group_by()` makes operations on a dataframe be performed "by group". After operations are finished, it's safer to use `ungroup()` to remove grouping; otherwise the data is still grouped.